# convert Graph objects to simple data arrays

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api

Since upgrading from v1 to v2 outputting let's say a Microsoft\Graph\Generated\Models\Event is huge and makes my browser crash when it's a few (writing debug log files).

I'm looking for a way to have a simple array with the properties I've requested, like:

```
[
   "subject" => "Meeting",
   "start" => "2024-02-03 20:00"
   "attendees" => [
       [
           "e-mail" => "someone@ms.com",
           "name" => "Lars",
           "status" => "accepted"
       ]
   ]
]
```